# How to add variable to the PATH on mac?

Tags: bash, rust, path

I am a smart contract developer. Recently, I am trying to elevate my development knowledge by learning Rust. However, I ran up against a tough problem at the beginning of the road. I am stuck with installing and storing Rust on PATH permanently.

I run this script in my terminal. "curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh"

Then according to this screenshot, it should be stored somewhere like this. And adding this directory to the PATH must yield constant access to RUST whenever a terminal is opened.
[image]

Then at the end, I am given this message informing of the installation success.

[image]

However, once I close the terminal, it seems RUST gets removed and I must reinstall it. I know that I should add its directory to my PATH, but I don't know how to modify my bash_profile properly.

Here is my PATH

[image]

Does anyone know how can I add the RUST directory to the PATH ( I assume I must add it to the bash_profile, but I don't know how to reach it )?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: it looks like you are echoing `path` rather than `PATH`. Make sure you are modifying the value of `PATH` instead of `path`

Comment: Also, have you tried logging out/back in or rebooting? Sometimes that is necessary to get the shell refreshed. I'm not sure if that is the case on MacOS.

Comment: The Rust directory is already in your path according to what you're showing us.

Comment: Keep in mind that `.zshenv` is sourced for *all* shells, whether interactive or not. IMO, it's not the place for defining environment variables, but rather for settings specific to the `zsh` notion of a shell environment. (Things like `zstyle` commands, etc.)

Comment: @joshmeranda looks like `path` env variable is a clone of `PATH`. I checked on mac already, seems legit to me.

Comment: `path` is used as an array variable in `zsh` which is now the default shell on macs.  This is very different from saying that `path` is a clone of `PATH` on all macs.  If you are using `bash` on your mac, then `path` is just a variable, and it is unrelated to PATH.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, none of the comments worked for me guys.

The reason for this issue was my MacOs version forces my terminal to use "~/.zshrc" instead of "~/.bash_profile" while getting opened.

I added the required directory to the zshrc instead of bash_profile and now I have access to Rust whenever I open a new terminal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JIzo.png)

Thanks all

Comment: MacOs does not "force" you to use zsh.  The default shell is zsh, but you are free to choose any shell you like.  But don't choose `csh`.